# runge kutta 4th order to solve system of differential equation

Tags: system, fortran, equation

```
dT/dt=(1.344-1.025T)/h (1)

dh/dt=0.025-(3.5*10^-4)*sqrt(h) (2)

h(0)=1

T(0)=1
```

I have to solve this system of equations in fortran. I solved the problem in matlab but I dont know fortran programming so guys if somebody can help me or somebody have the fortran code for this help me please please please 
thanks a lot

Comment: Try Rent-A-Coder.  This isn't a "do my homework" site.  Read enough Fortran to try something and post it when you have problems.  You'll get further with that approach.

Answer (score 3):

Try it with Euler integration.  Do something simple first.  You have one advantage: you've solved this once, so you know what the answer looks like when you get it.

Since the moderators are insisting this is a low quality answer because of the short length, I'll provide a working one in Java that should spark some thoughts for you.  I used the Apache Commons math library; it has several different ODE integration schemes, including Euler and Runge Kutta.

I ran this on a Windows 7 machine using JDK 8.  You can switch between Euler and Runge-Kutta using the command line:

```
package math.ode;

import org.apache.commons.math3.exception.DimensionMismatchException;
import org.apache.commons.math3.exception.MaxCountExceededException;
import org.apache.commons.math3.ode.FirstOrderDifferentialEquations;
import org.apache.commons.math3.ode.FirstOrderIntegrator;
import org.apache.commons.math3.ode.nonstiff.ClassicalRungeKuttaIntegrator;
import org.apache.commons.math3.ode.nonstiff.EulerIntegrator;

/**
 * IntegrationExample solves coupled ODEs using Euler and Runge Kutta
 * Created by Michael
 * Creation date 12/20/2015.
 * @link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20065521/dependencies-for-jama-in-maven
 */
public class IntegrationExample {

    public static final double DEFAULT_STEP_SIZE = 0.001;
    private static final double DEFAULT_MAX_TIME = 2.0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Problem set up
        double step = (args.length > 0) ? Double.valueOf(args[0]) : DEFAULT_STEP_SIZE;
        double maxTime = (args.length > 1) ? Double.valueOf(args[1]) : DEFAULT_MAX_TIME;
        String integratorName = (args.length > 2) ? args[2] : "euler";
        // Choose different integration schemes here.
        FirstOrderIntegrator firstOrderIntegrator = getFirstOrderIntegrator(step, integratorName);
        // Equations to solve here; see class below
        FirstOrderDifferentialEquations odes = new CoupledOdes();
        double [] y = ((CoupledOdes) odes).getInitialConditions();
        double t = 0.0;
        int i = 0;
        while (t <= maxTime) {
            System.out.println(String.format("%5d %10.6f %10.6f %10.6f", i, t, y[0], y[1]));
            firstOrderIntegrator.integrate(odes, t, y, t+step, y);
            t += step;
            ++i;
        }
    }

    private static FirstOrderIntegrator getFirstOrderIntegrator(double step, String integratorName) {
        FirstOrderIntegrator firstOrderIntegrator;
        if ("runge-kutta".equalsIgnoreCase(integratorName)) {
            firstOrderIntegrator = new ClassicalRungeKuttaIntegrator(step);
        } else {
            firstOrderIntegrator = new EulerIntegrator(step);
        }
        return firstOrderIntegrator;
    }
}

class CoupledOdes implements FirstOrderDifferentialEquations {

    public double [] getInitialConditions() {
        return new double [] { 1.0, 1.0 };
    }

    @Override
    public int getDimension() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public void computeDerivatives(double t, double[] y, double[] yDot) throws MaxCountExceededException, DimensionMismatchException {
        yDot[0] = (1.344-1.025*y[0])/y[1];
        yDot[1] = 0.025-3.5e-4*Math.sqrt(y[1]);
    }
}
```

You didn't say how far out you needed to integrate in time, so I assumed 2.0 as the max time.  You can change this on the command line, too.

Here's the plot of results versus time from Excel.  As you can see, the responses are smooth and well behaved.  Euler has no problem with systems of equations like this.

[image]

Comment: @duffymo: Could I recommend you to explain a bit more your answer? E.g: provide the Euler algorithm, and maybe an example of use for the provided question? (currently your answer is getting flagged as low-quality due to its low length)

Comment: Anyone using Matlab and Runge-Kutta will be able to switch to Euler - no explanation needed.  The problem of solving coupled ODEs should also be known.  This is analogous to being asked to solve a sorting problem and choosing between bubble and quick sort.  I assume that the OP has a minimum knowledge of their problem, even if you don't. Low quality?  Compared to what?  There are no other answers.

Comment: This ought to satisfy even the most ignorant comment troll.

Comment: I just noticed that the original answer was given over 4.5 years ago.