# Dependencies for Jama in Maven

Tags: eclipse, maven, jama

Where can i find `jama` dependencies for maven.

I checked in [MVN Repo](http://mvnrepository.com/) 
but could nt find.

```
I am using Jama-1.0.2.jar.
```

Any suggesions.

Comment: Best for searching is http://search.maven.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>gov.nist.math</groupId>
        <artifactId>jama</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
```